# Where's the Facebook C# SDK docs and examples?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-c#-sdk

I added the Facebook C# SDK package to my project but can't find any examples. The url in the help, http://csharpsdk.org, brings up a page about homework help.

Is this package no longer current? If not, what can be used instead of this?

I'm developing a facebook canvas app and need the ability to login from code and call all the relevant functions.
I thought that the new OWIN login in an MVC app would help but I couldn't figure out how to use it to automatically login and be able to make the different graph calls.

Thanks for any help. I've been fighting with this for some time now and can't seem to make progress.

Comment: correct address is : http://facebooksdk.net/

Comment: That redirect to https://hackerapp.com/ which doesn't have any documentation or examples either.

Answer (score 0):

See wiki documentation at github (pages on the right side) https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/wiki